# Notifying device based on their playstore account

Tags: android, android-service, google-play

I have Email Ids which are registered to `PlayStore` account. Can I send a notifications to the devices based on their Email Id.

Answer (score 0):

yes that is possible use google API to do it

Comment: use the content provider and intent